# What if you get distracted by something and started talking to someone while reading quran?

Tags: quran, reading-quran, surah

I was reading (Surah Al Yaseen) in my phone(mus-haf). All of a sudden, a rodent at a distance passed by me. I got distacted and looked at it for a moment until it escaped. After that, I conversed with my brother about something for a minute or two and then again started from where I stopped, and then completed it.

Is my reading of the whole surah valid ?

Comment: A device is not a mushaf.  A mushaf is a physical book with bookshelves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why shouldn't it be - we get distracted when reading all the time. It's valid as reading. Nevertheless, if you find yourself getting distracted all the time, it is better to put the Qu'ran down until your mind is less distracted by whatever is going on around you.

However, in prayer, when we recite surahs it is not valid as prayer, as the focus should be on the prayer, that is to be mindful of Allah.

In such a situation I would suggest that you start again; unless it is jummah prayer, in which case, I'd advise you to do better next time.

I'd also query why are you reading the Qu'ran in a place where 'rodents' are about. It's better to read in a clean and healthy environment. If it is in an educational establishment attached to a mosque, or otherwise; then I'd take this up with whoever is in charge of it.

**edit**

I'm replying to commentators here as I'm not able to reply to comments on my phone for some reason.

@Medi-Saif: It's not an opinion to use your own eyes and mind when you've been brought up in an Islamic tradition.  Or are you suggesting otherwise?

@Medi-Saif: Which is no different to what I was writing ... So what exactly are your real concerns  here?

@Crimson: I'm not addressing anyone with OCD. A person suffering from such should seek medical advice.

Comment: Is this your opinion or can you support it by any evidences?

Comment: AFAIK the only accepted reason for not answering Salam is if one reads /recites the qur'an. Therefore one should concentrate on Allah's message while reading it and not leave something distract you. If you feel like you get distracted you should stop the reading and put the Moshaf aside until you are ready to go ahead with your conversation with Allah's message.

Comment: Hopefully, someone with OCD never sees this.